# Write function with type parameter

Tags: scala, generics, scalatest, type-parameter

I have a unit test, which test some solution. But this test code can also be applied for testing the other, very similar solution. What I want to make is code of test be generic to be applied to both solutions, like this:

```
describe("when table contains all correct rows") {
      it("should be empty") {
        def check[T](func: T => List[Row]) = {
          val tableGen = new TableGenerator()
          val table: Vector[Row] = tableGen.randomTable(100)
            .sortWith(_.time isBefore _.time).distinct
          val result: List[Row] = func(table)
          assert(result.isEmpty)
        }

        check(Solution.solution1)
        check(Solution.solution2)
      }
    }
```

where solutions have types:

```
solution1: IndexedSeq[Row] => List[Row]
solution2: Seq[Row] => List[Row]
```

how **check()** function has to be written to be able to do that?
And what's the best approaches to write this (might be in other way) with eliminated code duplication?

**Update:**
When I try to compile this code I get type mismatch error in `func(table)`:

```
Error:(36, 29) type mismatch;
 found   : table.type (with underlying type scala.collection.immutable.Vector[com.vmalov.tinkoff.Row])
 required: T
          val result = func(table)
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to do anything? This `check` function should already be able do that, and there is no duplicate code to be eliminated in what you've shown.

Comment: Once I'm trying to compile I get type mismatch error: found Vector[Row], required T (table I pass to func).
The second question was about may be there is another, better/prefferable way to abstract such things.

Comment: You should add that in the question.

Comment: Ok, sorry, missed a bit.

Comment: I recommend you add a message with something to help identify the test, otherwise if a test fails, you won't know quickly which of the two did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to work, you need to be able to pass a `Vector[Row]` to `func`, so any `Vector[Row]` has to be a `T`; that is, `T` is a supertype of `Vector[Row]`. You can tell this to the compiler by using a type parameter bound:

```
def check[T >: Vector[Row]](func: T => List[Row])
```

Alternately, by the above reasoning, a function `T => List[Row]` will also be a function `Vector[Row] => List[Row]` precisely when `T` is a supertype of `Vector[Row]`, and the Scala compiler knows about this (functions are *contravariant* in their argument type(s)). So this signature is equivalent to simpler

```
def check(func: Vector[Row] => List[Row])
```

Of course, you can generalize this, but how much depends on your specific desires. E.g. you can replace `List[Row]` with `Seq[Row]` (everywhere), or with a type parameter and pass an extra function to `check`:

```
def check[A](func: Vector[Row] => A)(test: A => Boolean) = {
  val table = ...
  val result = func(table)
  assert(test(result))
}

check(Solution.solution1)(_.isEmpty) // the compiler infers A is List[Row]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Your case, maybe is enough to abstract the type on a more specific way, like defining that you are expecting a Travesable.

```
  def check[S[_] : Traversable](func: S[Row] => List[Row])
```

That would accept either Seq or IndexedSeq as valid parameter, while it also be limiting it.

I hope it helps

EDITED: Check Alexey Romanov Answer, as with this you will not be able to call func the way you do it. Sorry about that

def check(func: Vector[Row] => List[Row])

Comment: I think you mean `S[X] <: Traversable[X]`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the issue, I was too quickly answering :P but Alexey Romanov seems to have answered this one pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for response. But indeed, this doesn't solve the problem.